# compare 2 fixed length flat files based on fields in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am new to unix and have a requirment to merge two fixed length flat file and have common
 record(s) which are transaction id and batch num.

In file1.txt the transaction id is from 1 thru 10 and batch id is from 19 to 21.
In file2.txt the transaction id is from 12 thru 21 and batch id is from 30 to 32.

For the lines/records matching in both files, cut/copy the invoice number from file2.txt and append that at last in file1.txt. The invoice number is not in same line as my trans id, & batch number.

Someone please help.

***  Sample input - File1.txt ***

```
161065730303122012098
161065846403042011784
161065916903012012431
161066813503042019678
161066835008092012136
161067040701122012984
161067106602122010267
```

***  Sample input - File2.txt ***

```
2.60E5-2670161065730303122012098
userid 234
date03122012
Invnum987678
2.60E5-2670161065846403042011098
userid 871
date03122012
Invnum987912
2.60E5-2670161065916903012012075
userid 871
date031610671066122012
Invnum987654
2.60E5-2670161066813503042011075
userid 871
date03122012
Invnum987322
2.60E5-2670161066835008092012075
userid 871
date03122012
Invnum987323
2.60E5-2670161067040701122012075
userid 871
date03122012
Invnum987324
2.60E5-2670161067106602122010074
userid 811
date03122012
Invnum987325
```

---

**Desired output**

```
161065730303122012098987678
161065846403042011784987912
161065916903012012431987654
161066813503042019678987322
161066835008092012136987323
161067040701122012984987324
161067106602122010267987325
```

Comment: [When you tried doing this yourself](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), with which part of the problem did you get stuck? If you share your code we may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, I have not coded anything yet. I am trying to build loigc and then translate that to code.

Comment: 4th line in desired output is how `161066813503042019678987322` ? for me its doubtful..

Comment: @Awk, What is doubtful? are you talking about typo in the date?

Comment: How do you expect `161066813503042019678987322` as you have mentioned in desired output .. did you try code posted below ?

Comment: Try it yourself.  Try *something*.  Give us something to go off of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
              if(length($0)==32)
              p = substr($0,12,18)
              if(/Invnum.*/)
              A[p]=substr($0,7)
              next
             }
((s=substr($1,1,18)) in A){ print $1 A[s] }' file2 file1.txt
```

**--edit---**

one liner

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {if(length($0)==32)p = substr($0,12,18);if(/Invnum.*/)A[p]=substr($0,7);next}((s=substr($1,1,18)) in A){ print $1 A[s] }' file2 file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am afraid if my line does not start with "2.60E5" this will not work.

Comment: Okay change `if(/2\.60E5-.*/)` to `if(/-.*/)` or `if(length($0)==32)` it will work.

Comment: I ran as-is and below is the output. The invoice num is repeating and not pickup the right inv#. I may need to tweak something here.                            161065730303122012098987654 161065846403042011784987654 161065916903012012431987654 161066813503042019678987325 161066835008092012136987325 161067040701122012984987325 161067106602122010267987325

Comment: Thanks Awk. The one liner is fantastic. I actually wanted to lookup 2 fields (trnx id & batch id) in file2 and generate the output.

Comment: @Awk Why are you adding `0`?

Comment: @Jaypal Singh if there is any unseen space char it will be removed if you add `0` its because `( var in Array)` won't work it looks for exact match of index.

Comment: @Awk True, but if you see sample data only one (first line) key is present in the array you create from second file. The output you get displays index that aren't even present. I don't know why though. :)

Comment: @ Jaypal : Yes ! Brother, you are right I just corrected please don't mind.. But really don't know how its worked you must have tried also I think.. :)

Comment: @Awk Yeah, and went crazy thinking why it did work! :)

Comment: @ Jaypal did you get answer finally ??

Comment: @Awk Nope ... will do some research. What I saw was adding 0 some how corrupted the index. If you just put an END Block and check the index you will see different values from the ones captured.

Comment: @ Jaypak Exactly I still could not find the reason for that, actually as I said earlier, I just wanted to remove spaces, since data is integer even if you add `0`, it should not affect index theoretically, but this is some interesting problem, tomorrow I will try with `nawk` in office.. if you get answer please let me know..

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
awk -F"-" '
NR==FNR && NF>1 {
    v=substr($2,5,18);
    next
}
NR==FNR && /Invnum/ {
    sub(/Invnum/,"",$0);
    a[v]=$0;
    next
}
(substr($0,1,18) in a) {
    print $0 a[substr($0,1,18)]
}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

**Output:**

```
161065730303122012098987678
161065846403042011784987912
161065916903012012431987654
161066835008092012136987323
161067040701122012984987324
161067106602122010267987325
```

Answer (score 0):

i've used files a.txt and b.txt

```
for i in `cat b.txt`; do; a=$(echo $i|cut -c1-10); echo $(grep $a a.txt|cut -c12-)$(grep -A3 $a a.txt|tail -n1|cut -c7-) ;done
161065730303122012098987678
161065846403042011098987912
161065916903012012075987654
161066813503042011075987322
161066835008092012075987323
161067040701122012075987324
161067106602122010074987325
```

is this ok?

Comment: Thanks. This one works however I want to lookup for 2 fields. I have trxn id and batchid in file1, not sure where to fit the batch id here. I tried few things but didnt work.